# Vectorizing text from data frame column using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a Data Frame which looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to vectorize every row, but only from the text column. I wrote this code:

```
vectorizerCount = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
# tokenize and build vocab
allDataVectorized = allData.apply(vectorizerCount.fit_transform(allData.iloc[:]['headline_text']), axis=1)
```

The error says:

> TypeError: ("'csr_matrix' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')

Doing some research and trying changes I found out the fit_transform function returns a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix and that is not callable.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are applying countvectorizer to both the columns with publish_date being int, and hence the error. Try vectorizerCount.fit(all_Data.headline_text)

Comment: Thanks, I think it is almost that. I did allDataVectorized = allData.apply(vectorizerCount.fit_transform(allData.headline_text), axis=1) and returned "'csr_matrix' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0'

Comment: I changed the question to your idea :) I will investigate more

Comment: Weel, I found out that transform_fit returns a sparse matrix and that is not callable. I will edit the question again

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code. You probably need something like

```
allDataVectorized = pd.DataFrame(vectorizerCount.fit_transform(allData[['headline_text']]))
```

- `allData[['headline_text']])` (with the double brackets) is a DataFrame, which transforms to a numpy 2d array.
- `fit_transform` returns a csr matrix.
- `pd.DataFrame(...)` creates a DataFrame from a csr matrix.

Comment: I understand. I saw some of these problems. Right now I am looking at sparse matrices and trying to do this without Data Frames. Already have these columns in separate Series and managed to vectorize the one I want, but need to associate with da year Series

Comment: @Pvic You might want to check out [sparse DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) - personally I find using numpy directly to be very error prone.